# expecting statement -php syntax | if-else

Tags: php, syntax

```
 <?php if ( wp_get_attachment_image($item['image']['id'], 'home-post-thumbnail')  !='' ) { ?>
         <?php echo wp_get_attachment_image( $item['image']['id'], 'home-post-thumbnail' ); } ?>
                                          <?php else {
                        ?> <img class="img-responsive img-whp" src="<?php echo plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . '/6-450x450.jpg'; ?>">
                                        <?php  } ?>
```

I get critical error.phpstorms says that expecting statements.I couldnt find a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot "interrupt" the PHP code after the closing `{` of the `if` and before the `else` keyword.

Cleaned up version:

```php
<?php if (wp_get_attachment_image($item['image']['id'], 'home-post-thumbnail') != '') {
    echo wp_get_attachment_image($item['image']['id'], 'home-post-thumbnail');
} else {
    ?><img class="img-responsive img-whp" src="<?php echo plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . '/6-450x450.jpg'; ?>"><?php
} ?>
```

To avoid such errors, try learning and following a coding standard, e.g. [PSR-12](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/).

Since you are working with WordPress, here is WP's coding standard for PHP: https://developer.wordpress.org/coding-standards/wordpress-coding-standards/php/